# How to change permissions of Oracle generated logs?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, permissions, logs, solaris

The oracle generated logs (ie. alert and listener logs) are being created with 600 permissions. These files are of course created automatically by the oracle user. How would I change the permissions to automatically be 640, for instance, in a Solaris 10 environment? This would allow DBAs to read them and such without logging into the oracle user account.

Comment: What filesystem are you using ZFS/XFS/? You can do it with ACLs. Can probably also manage it with a chmod +s, and a correctly set `umask` when starting the RDBMS

Comment: Have you tried changing permissions on the folder where the log files are located?  Set up inherited permissions.